# jQuery: How to use each starting at an index other than 0

Tags: jquery, each

I have a collection of elements that I want to loop over using each, but I am looping over them inside an outer for loop. When I find what I want in the each, I return false to break out. The next time the outer loop runs, I want to start in the each at the element after the one I returned at. A generic code example:

```
var nextIndex = 0;

for (var j=1; j <= someCount; j++) {
    // do outside loop stuff

    $('#someElemID').find('.someClass').each(function(index) {
        if (/*this is right one*/) {
            // do something
            // next index should get passed to each function next loop... somehow?
            nextIndex = index + 1; 
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I thought about switching to a for loop, but then I got confused as to how to access the return from the `.find('.someClass')`. Maybe that's a separate question itself...

Is this an obvious one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `slice()` http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$('#someElemID').find('.someClass').slice(nextIndex).each( ...
```

---

btw if the elements are static, consider caching:

```
var $elms = $('.someClass', '#someElemID'),
    nextIndex = 0;

for (var j = 1; j <= someCount; j++) {
    // do outside loop stuff

    $elms.slice(nextIndex).each(function(index) {
        if (/*this is right one*/) {
            nextIndex = index + 1; 
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

That should improve performance considerably.

Comment: This, with a little modification, did exactly what I needed with the least changes to my existing code! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to store the index unincremented, then you can use the [gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to directly select elements which occur after the stored index, like this:

```
$('#someElemID .someClass:gt(' + storedIndex + ')').each(function() {
    ...
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the gt selector. Didn't realize you could use it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how often you are going to run this or how many different varitions you need, but I'm not fond of leaving `nextValue` floating around in space. You could do something like this, which would give you the availability to create multiple different 'queues' if you will. It sounds like you only want to find that item once, and once you do you  never want to search it again. This should do just that, and it works by caching the selector. If you are changing the DOM between calls, use one of the other answers.

```
nameThisFunction = function(s) {
    var self = this;
    this.selector = $(s);
    return function(searchFor) {
        self.selector.each(function(i) {
            if (/*Do your comparision to searchFor*/) {
                // Do what you want
                self.selector.splice(i, 1);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
};

var thisQueue = new nameThisFunction('#someElemId .someClass');

thisQueue('Search for something here');
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robert/RCfeJ/

Comment: +1 because you showed me yet another way I wouldn't have thought of doing this. I need to go ponder this one some more... so much to learn! Thanks.