# How to output json results with position

Tags: jquery, json

I have json below

```
["DATA 1", "DATA 2", "DATA 3"]
```

In normal when I want output each value I using :

```
$.each(json,function(key,value){
   alert(value);
});
```

Now I want output from DATA 2 and not output DATA 1.

How to do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760734/jquery-how-to-use-each-starting-at-an-index-other-than-0

Comment: Is that a Json or an array?

Comment: $.each(json,function(key,value){
  if (key > 0) {
     // DO stuff
  }
});

Comment: I cannot understand why you want to iterate trough each value if you know the one you want to use. Access it directly instead with index 1.

Comment: @JohanSundén I want output all value after index 0 not only index 1 :)

Comment: Ok, but then the you should check if key is greater or equal to 1. Or just greater than 0. The given answer will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you as I understood want's to use all values after index 0, you need to check if index is greater than 0, and not equal to 1.

```
var json = ["DATA 1", "DATA 2", "DATA 3"];

$.each(json, function eachClosure(key, value) {
    if (key > 0) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(json,function(key,value){
  if (key === 1) {
     //Only for second element. But in this case, what is the loop for?
     alert(value);
  }
});
```