# Jquery each loop iteration

Tags: jquery, each, instafeedjs

Is it possible with the jquery each loop to start at index 20 after clicking on a load more button? i cant get it right because the loop start every time at 0....

Kind regards,

Stephan

```
after:function() {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    var len = images.length;

    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');   
    }); 

    $('#loadmore').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      index = 20;
      feed.next();
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760734/jquery-how-to-use-each-starting-at-an-index-other-than-0

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is, just slice the jQuery collection

```
$.each(images.slice(20), function(index, image) { ...
```