# Start jquery each from 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var nums = [];

$('#table_serv tr td.serv-nomer').each(function (elem, ind) {
    nums[parseInt($(this).text())] = elem;
    $(this).text(elem);
});
```

I need to start each `elem` at 1. But now `elem` start from `0`, can be and starts from `1`. Differently. How I can do fix starts from `1` ?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the first element in the matched set to be included? Just do `td.serv-nomer:gt(1)`.

Comment: @BenM I thought he meant that he wanted to skip the first element in the loop ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip first N elements in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213961/skip-first-n-elements-in-jquery) and [jQuery: How to use each starting at an index other than 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760734)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not(':first')` to remove the first element from the selector:

```
$('#table_serv tr td.serv-nomer').not(':first').each(function (elem, ind) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
var nums = [];

$('#table_serv tr td.serv-nomer').each(function (elem, ind) {
    if(elem > 0 ) {
        nums[parseInt($(this).text())] = elem;
        $(this).text(elem);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To not include first Iteration or element at 0 index then:

```
var nums = [];

    $('#table_serv tr td.serv-nomer').each(function (elem, ind) {
    if (elem != "0")
    {
        nums[parseInt($(this).text())] = elem;
        $(this).text(elem);
    }
    });
```

Or if you want to iterate for just item at index 1 then you can do like this:

```
var nums = [];

    $('#table_serv tr td.serv-nomer').each(function (elem, ind) {
    if (elem == 1)
    {
        nums[parseInt($(this).text())] = elem;
        $(this).text(elem);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to start the array with 1 instead of 0

```
$("a").each(function (i, e) {
titles[i + 1] = $(this).text() })
```